# How to authorize Zoom for G Suite extension

Tags: google-calendar, g-suite-administrator, zoom.us

I use G Suite for my personal email. I installed the [Zoom for GSuite](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/zoom_for_gsuite/364750910244) extension so that I can add Zoom video conferencing to Google Calendar events.

When I select Zoom as a conference option, I'm prompted to log in to my Zoom account, and then I'm given this error screen (as you can see I already clicked the request button):
[image]

I *am* the admin for my G Suite organization, and I don't know how to grant this pre-approval. I've poked around the G Suite admin panel a lot but haven't had any luck.